# localhost and IP Address issue

Tags: iis, webserver, localhost, ip-address

I have this irritating problem on my web development. I have an issue regarding the usage of `http://localhos`t and my IP address http://10.xxx.xx.x. If I access my website using my localhost which is also 127.0.0.1, it renders good, but when I access it on other workstation, the rendering is really bad. So I tried to use my ip address, then it looks the same as what the others can see. As a developer this is the first time I encountered it because this is my first time using ISS web servers. I really dont know if it is an IIS problem or is it just me. hehe..
One thing also is Im using a server side program which Im updating and it seems that when I use my ip address, the update has not been displayed. It would took a day or two to update it. Is there anyone here experience the same problem and fixed it. Or is there any IIS guru's here that can help me. I really dont know what to do. Im having an inconsistent website. :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: >> the rendering is really bad?  What does that mean?  Is it possible there is a CSS file on the local machine that isn't being accessed by remote users?

Comment: When on another workstation: You seem to say that when you are using the IP address, it looks fine. What URL are you using the rest of the time? If you are using `http://localhost/` from another workstation, then you are looking at something _on that workstation_, not on your computer...

Answer (score 1):

Check through all your HTML and check all URLs that point to resources within the site. Make sure they start with `/` instead of `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`. For example, replace `http://localhost/images/logo.png` with `/images/logo.png`

It would be great if you could add more details to your question. Also, you might try using the Firebug extension for Firefox to determine if any stylesheets, images, or scripts are failing to load.

Comment: why do you think this is the problem? do you think it has something to do with my website being outdated when im using my ip address and updated when im using localhost. they display differently. :(

Comment: It's impossible for me to be sure, without seeing what you are seeing. However, if you have any URLs in your HTML beginning with `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`, you can be certain that it will cause a problem, because other computers will try to load those resources from their own hard drives, rather than from your computer.

Comment: As Mark said, It is always suggested to use the relative urls than the absolute urls. And using IP address or localhost in url is not encouraged, as each system will have a different IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i experience this problem all the time, after digging, it turned out to be a problem with my ISP, they cache certain files according to ip address... so to get over it in development mode (debug mode) i add a random number to all my css and js files (/styles/ui.css?34), i do that programmatically so that i dont have to worry about it, when im done, i fix the version and turn debug off on live host